# ExtJS Chart Hide Grid

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4

I'm using the axis.drawGrid() method but I'd also like to use something like axis.hideGrid() , is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's doable. I use the following code to hide grid lines on each axis.

```
chart.axes.getAt(index).gridLines.hide(true)
```